# How to calculate initial RC5 encryption parameters?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, rc5

[image]

I learn from a minithesis to understand RC5.
As we can see at the formula, the round 0 must be using A=A+S[0], because the loop is starting at r(round) 1.

I tried addition and OR(bitwise) to get the answer DA679BFB but keep missing, Here is my result of calculating.

```
A = A + S[0]

  = 4B726970 + BF0A8B1D

  = 10A7CF48D


A = A OR S[0]

  = 4B726970 OR BF0A8B1D

  = FF7AEB7D
```

The S Data is the result of 3rd phase key expanding on RC5. I really need help because I have been stuck here for 2 days and thank you in advance.

```
Plaintext : 4B726970 746F2053 74656761 6E6F
key       : 4B726970 746F6772 616669 
w(blocksize) = 32, r(round) = 12, b(key lenght) = 16
```

Comment: Could you specify the RC5 input parameters used? I'm assuming the word size is 32, the number of rounds is 12, and the key is all zeroes?

Comment: The most important check you can do is in your endianness, since RC5 is little-endian. So your first word may be 70 69 72 4B.

Comment: Finally, how much trust are you placing in this "minithesis" being correct?

Comment: I put more information in the post,  And i trust this minithesis sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you should use addition, not XOR. Next, if you're doing this calculation with a computer, make sure you're processing the bytes as little-endian, and that you pad your key to the 16 bytes you mentioned:

`4B726970 746F6772 61666900 00000000`

Now, you have basically answered the question yourself of why you aren't getting the correct value:

> The S Data is the result of 3rd phase key expanding on RC5.

The formula `A = A + S[0]` is correct, but as you note there are multiple phases of mixing the $L$ and $S$ arrays. During the first phase, $A$ and $B$ look like:

```
i=1 A= **0xbf0a8b1d** B= **0x5ee7fad**
i=2 A= 0xd88eaf30 B= 0x2a1c93ca
i=3 A= 0xb7dc3e7f B= 0xc47155c4
...
```

These are the values on the right-hand side of the image you posted. The value `0xbf0a8b1d` in particular is the one you've been trying to add. What you should be using are values from the 3rd phase:

```
i=1 A= **0x8ef5328b** B= **0x600e18b6**
i=2 A= 0x64aa69d0 B= 0x384a0d6
i=3 A= 0x7a471ae8 B= 0xd5a140fa
...
```

So now, take your plaintext word `0x4b726970` and add it to `0x8ef5328b`, and you get the desired value of `0xda679b7b`:

```
i=1 A= **0xda679bfb** B= 0xd9198a23 # before the loop even starts
i=2 A= 0x9637a9a8 B= 0x7e949194
i=3 A= 0x4ec0dda1 B= 0x299ed426
...
```

I followed [Rivest's paper on RC5](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv94.pdf) and double-checked my values against a Python implementation. We don't do implementation details here, but that should answer why you haven't been able to match up to that example.

Comment: So on the 2nd phase its using the new S and L from the 1st phase since A and B is back to zero, right? Thank you again sir.

Comment: S and L are continually updated on each phase, yes. A and B represent registers containing the plaintext. Once the algorithm starts, A and B are never reset to zero.